# Msg 2627 Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint

Tags: mysql, primary-key, constraint, duplication

trying to make a database for teams in a tv show here. but when I try and insert data into tblShowteam the following error made its appearance.

```
Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 2
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__tblShowt__F693078C03317E3D'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.tblShowteam'.
```

**tables**

```
-- tabbellen aanmaken
create table tblShow(
setId       int,
Datum       date,
teams       int
primary key (setId));

create table tblShowteam(
SetId           int,
datum           date,
teams           int,
primary key (teams));


create table tblTeam(
TeamId      int,
Coach       varchar(35),
CoachId     int,
teams       int
primary key (CoachId));


-- participant table
create table tblDeelnemer(
DeelnemerId     int identity(1, 1),
DeelnemerV      varchar(35),
deelnemerT_V    varchar(10),
DeelnemerA      varchar(35),
CoachId         int,
datum_optreden  date
primary key (DeelnemerId));


--table for the public viewers
create table tblKijker(
Kijkerv         varchar(35),
KijkerT_V       varchar(10),
KijkerA         varchar(35),
Stoelnummer     int identity(1,3),
ShowId          int Not null,
Email           varchar(35)
primary key (Email));
```

my **inserts** would look like this:

```
insert into tblShowteam values (1, '2014-06-28', 1)
insert into tblShowteam values (2, '2014-06-05', 1)
insert into tblShowteam values (3, '2014-06-12', 1)
insert into tblShowteam values (4, '2014-06-19', 1)
insert into tblShowteam values (5, '2014-06-26', 1)
all other inserts (in diffrent tables) work like normal.
```

what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Why on earth are you adding the `tbl` suffix in all tables?

Comment: On the question, what is the `ShowTeam` table about? Is it a junction (intersection, many-to-many) table between tables `Show` and `Team`?

Answer (score 1):

tblShowteam has primary key on `teams` column  (

> create table tblShowteam(
>   SetId           int,
>   datum           date,
>   teams           int,
>   primary key (teams));

You are inserting rows with the same primary key (1) multiple time :

```
insert into tblShowteam values (1, '2014-06-28', 1);  
--the same as  "insert into tblShowteam (SetId,datum,teams) VALUES (...,1);
insert into tblShowteam values (2, '2014-06-05', 1) ; --it's gonna fail , record with 
-- teams = 1 already exists
```

I guess `setId` was supposed to be primary key, not `teams`.

Answer (score 0):

In create table you have set **teams** as primary key, and also you are aware that primary key does not allow duplicate values.

```
mysql> create table tblShowteam(
        -> SetId           int,
        -> datum           date,
        -> teams           int,
        -> primary key (teams));
    Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.13 sec)
```

Check the insert query for **teams** field you have mentioned values as 1 and if you insert the same value for second record it will behave as below.

```
   mysql> insert into tblShowteam values (1, '2014-06-28', 1);
    Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)

    mysql> insert into tblShowteam values (2, '2014-06-05', 1);
    ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Please alter and keep **SetId** as primary key.